# Is the portfolio return distribution a weighted combination of individual asset return distributions?

Tags: statistics, probability, portfolio-selection

We know that the **portfolio expected return** is a weighted sum of the individual assets' expected returns (asset means). We also know that the **portfolio variance** is a weighted combination of the individual assets' volatilities. More specifically, it's a quadratically weighted functional of the volatilities and covariances/correlations.

Is the **portfolio return distribution** $\text{P}(Xw)$ likewise some sort of weighted combination of the individual assets' return distributions? where $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$ is the multivariate asset returns matrix, and $w\in \mathbb{R}^k$ is the portfolio weight vector whose elements are fractions that sum to 1, making $Xw$ the portfolio's $n\times 1$-shaped return series vector. by "distribution", interested in both the pdf and cdf cases.

Comment: *We also know that the portfolio variance is a weighted combination of the individual assets' volatilities.* I guess you forgot the covariances... Oh, you did not: *More specifically, it's a quadratically weighted functional of the volatilities and covariances/correlations.* OK, so you are in conflict with yourself there.

Answer (score 3):

As @Martin has pointed out in his answer, of course it is.

Let $X=\sum_{i=1}^N w_ix_i$ denote the return of a portfolio of $N$ assets with multivariate distribution $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N)$.

The distribution of $X$ may be found by $(N-1)$-fold [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of the $N$-dimensional distribution $f$. Unfortunately, the integrals are not that easily solved anymore.

Another way to solve this is to try and find the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) of your portfolio return. This is usually *a bit* less complicated and you can then use complex numerical integration to find the distribution - which is nasty in itself as well.

A third way is to *simply* simulate from your distribution and moment-match a flexible distribution or use some other form of distribution approximation (e.g. kernel methods).

HTH?

Comment: wish I could see a derivation of a portolio return distribution's characteristic function based on a convolution of Gaussin or t-distributions. let me know if there's a source demonstrating how this can be derived. In the same way that we have formulas for the portfolio expected return and portfolio variance being weighted combinations of their inputs, my question really was trying to draw out a similar formulation of a weighted-pdf/cdf combo

Comment: For the multivariate normal, you can directly look it up (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution). The multivariate $t$ distribution is quite complicated (at least for me), but you might be able to find something online, e.g. here http://www.csam.or.kr/journal/download_pdf.php?spage=81&volume=21&number=1

Comment: alot of the probability genres, like concentration of measure, and convolutions, tend to always assume the marginals are independent though, which is not the case for asset returns. your link included even says "The [characteristic functions] allow us to easily manipulate convolved probability density functions (pdfs) when they represent linear combinations of *independent* random variables."

Comment: For normals, cou can de-correlate the variables using the cholesky matrix. Then, you have loadings on independent RVs. This 'trick' can be applied in various applications. Ultimatively, you always need to know *how* to disentangle your RVs...

Comment: is it easy to extract the weight vector from a convolution? for example `scipy` `convolve1d` or `numpy.convolve` (the latter function is restricted to only 2 components)

Comment: Hi, I think you think this the wrong way round. First, the convolve function is, usually, for discrete convolutions. We are talking integrals here. Second, I think you might want to read a bit more on the statistics / math behind this - That will get you a lot of mileage.

Comment: I'm guessing there must be drawbacks then of using convolutions to model portfolio distributions and hope to learn what they are in the readings. but how everyone pointed out in a closed post of mine, finance by default takes asset distributions to be discrete anyway, simply because they are finite-sampled, so I don't think I was talking about integrals here

Comment: in terms of portfolio optimization, where we are interested in portfolio weight instructions, convolutions are of no value to the investment process if they cannot even provide portfolio weights

Comment: @develarist: Take a simple case that occurs in finance, where you want to know the distribution of a sum of logNormal variables. This simple case has no tractable exact pdf (only various approximations). Unless you assume Gaussian marginals... then life becomes much easier...

Comment: and also very wrong since returns are non-Gaussian and fat tailed

Comment: @develarist, which closed post of yours are you referring to?